# Optimal solutions of two related linear programs Ax=b and Ay=0

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Let $x$ be a feasible solution to the following linear program: 
$$\min c^tx \\ Ax=b \\x\ge0 $$
Let $Z=\{i | x_i=0\}$. Prove that $x$ is an optimal solution if and only if the optimal value of the following linear program is $0$:
$$\min c^ty \\ Ay=0 \\y_i\ge0 \quad \forall i\in Z$$

My main thought here is that if we can show that the null-space of the latter is of size $0$, then by the null-space properties it follows that the optimal solution is $0$.

Comment: Hint: If $A$ is invertible, then making the association $x=y+A^{-1} b$ lets you go between the two programs.

Comment: Thank you @angryavian! Exactly what I needed to see

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure completely why this equality holds. We can break down $x$ to $x=x_B+x_Z$, for $B=\{i|x_i>0\}$. And as $x$ is optimal it follows that $x_B=A^{-1} b$. But I'm not sure why should $x_Z$ be equivalent to $y$. Aren't they from different dimensions? @angryavian

Comment: Sorry, assuming $A$ is invertible is silly. I will reformulate an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I managed to prove this:

---

Denote by $P$ the first LP and by $P'$ the second LP.

$\Rightarrow$ 
Assume that $x$ is an optimal solution to $P$, and assume that $ \exists y \,s.t. \, \forall i\in Z:\, y_i\ge0 \,\wedge c^ty<0$. w.l.o.g assume that $y_{i^*}=\max_i\{|y_i|\}\le1$ (otherwise, we can choose $y'=y/|y_{i^*}|$).

Define $\varepsilon=\min_{i\notin Z }\{x_i\}$, and notice that $\varepsilon>0$ since $\forall i: x_i \ge 0 \, , \, Z=\{i | x_i=0\}$. Let $x'=x+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, it follows that:
$$ c^tx'=c^tx+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}c^ty<c^tx $$
$$ Ax'=Ax+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}Ay=b+0=b $$
$$ i\in Z: x'_i=x_i+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}y_i=y_i\ge0 $$
$$ i\notin Z: x'_i=x_i+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}y_i\ge x_i-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}y_{i^*}>0 $$
We got a contradiction, as $x'$ is a feasible solution to $P$ for which a smaller solution value than that of $x$ is obtained. Thus, $c^ty\ge0$. Now, as $y=0$ is a feasible solution to $P'$ with a solution value of $0$, it follows that the optimal solution value of $P'$ is $0$.

$\Leftarrow$ Assume that the optimal solution value of $P'$ is $0$, and denote by $y$ a solution for which this value is obtained. Assume that $x$ is not optimal, then there exists a solution $x'\neq x$ for which $c^tx'<c^tx$. Define $y'=x'-x$, then one can see that $y'$ is a feasible solution of $P'$ for which a smaller solution value than that of $y$ is obtained:
$$ c^ty' = c^tx'-c^tx<0$$
$$ Ay' = Ax'-Ax=b-b=0$$
$$ \forall i\in Z: y_i'=x_i'-x_i=x_i'\ge0$$

We got a contradiction for the optimal solution value of $P'$ being $0$, since there is a solution $y'$ for which a negative solution value is obtained. Thus, $x$ is an optimal solution of $P$.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for my earlier bad hint. Here is probably the correct approach, but I am unable to deal with an extra constraint in the second program. Perhaps you or someone else can fix this issue.

---

Fix some $z$ that is feasible for the first program. Then any vector $x$ satisfying $Ax=b$ can be written as $z+y$ for some $y$ in the nullspace of $A$.

Let $Z=\{i : z_i = 0\}$.
The following optimization problems are equivalent.
\begin{align}
&\min_x c^\top x & Ax=b, x \ge 0\\
& c^\top z + \min_y c^\top y & Ay=0, y+z \ge 0\\
& c^\top z + \min_y c^\top y & Ay=0; y_i \ge 0, \forall i \in Z; y_i \ge -z_i, \forall i \notin Z
\end{align}

---

In particular if $z$ is the optimizer of the first program, then $z=z+0$ so $0$ must be the optimizer to the problem $\min_y c^\top y$ s.t. $Ay=0$, $y_i \ge 0$ for $i \in Z$, and $y_i \ge -z_i$ for $i \notin Z$. The converse holds as well.

However, I am unable to get rid of the constraint $y_i \ge -z_i \forall i \notin Z$.

Comment: I added my final solution